# Microphones Not Working with 12.04

Tags: 12.04, microphone

Installed Ubuntu precise pangolin and everything is working fine except for my microphones (both internal and external). I have updated the drivers and installed alsa, to no avail. What to do?

Comment: Can you please add some hardware detail?

Comment: make sure your microphone isn't muted.. I believe it is muted by default...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say you installed alsa, do you mean you installed alsamixer?  If not, install alsamixer, pull it up and check to make sure you microphones aren't muted.

```
$ sudo apt-get install alsamixer
```

Assuming alsamixer is ruled out, post up the output of:

```
$ arecord -l
```

Comment: I solved opening alsamixer, F4 to go to capture screen, that go to Input Source and changed from "Line" to "Front Mic".